# How do i add Link to firebase cloud messaging with .net admin sdk

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am using the Firebase .net Admin SDK on my back end to send push notifications.

According to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) I should be able to add the following json into a message object that will open the set link when the notification is clicked on while the app is in background.

```
  "webpush": {
    "fcm_options": {
      "link": "https://dummypage.com"
    }
```

I have read through the [.net Admin Sdk documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet/) but cannot figure out where to add this. 
Here is the code that I used to new up the message object

```
var fcm = FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance;
var Message = new Message()
  {
    Notification = new Notification
      {
        Title = title,
        Body = message,
      },
    Token = user.PushTokenWeb,
  };
var result = await fcm.SendAsync(Message);
```

Does anyone know where I would set the callback link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET SDK does not support this setting yet. It's only exposed in Node.js and Go at the moment. You can provide a pull request at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet to implement this feature.

Comment: How to add sound and android_channel_id in it?

Answer (score 5):

In FirebaseAdmin .net v1.9.0 you can

```
    var message = new Message()
    {
        Token = token,
        Notification = new Notification()
        {
            Body = notificationBody,
            Title = title
        },
        Android = new AndroidConfig()
        {
            Priority = Priority.High
        },
        Webpush = new WebpushConfig()
        {
            FcmOptions = new WebpushFcmOptions()
            {
                 Link= "https://www.davnec.eu/aurora-boreale/previsioni/"
            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: How to add sound and android_channel_id in it?